# Is there a way to compare text from textarea and change the button text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend, web-frontend

**I am working on a small project. I have a textarea and a button(Send). I am trying to compare the text of a textarea which already written last time. If I update this time it compares and find any change in textarea it will change the text of button(save changes)**

Comment: sounds like a problem, we would be interested to see how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the button text state on any change event in your textarea component. This is straightforward and simple to do in React. You could further sophisticate this logic by storing the previously saved message in state and comparing it to the textarea content.

I take it you also want to reset the button text after saving changes?

Here's an example of how to implement which you can extend to add a more robust diffing mechanism if desired:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Send");

  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    setButtonText("Save Changes");
  }

  function handleClick() {
    setButtonText("Send");
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto",
        width: "200px"
      }}
    >
      <textarea rows={6} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
      <button style={{ margin: "10px" }} onClick={handleClick}>
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-waterfall-c28h6p?file=/src/App.tsx